# Speed up selecting elements in combined netCDF files using Xarray and Dask

Tags: dask, python-xarray

I am new to Xarray and Dask and trying to access multiple netCDF files that store global ocean current velocities on 3H interval. Each netCDF file covers one time interval of gridded data of 1/4 degree resolution:

```
NetCDF dimension information:
Name: time
    size: 1
    type: dtype('float32')
    _FillValue: 9.96921e+36
    units: 'days since 1950-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
    calendar: 'julian'
    axis: 'T'
Name: lat
    size: 720
    type: dtype('float32')
    _FillValue: 9.96921e+36
    units: 'degrees_north'
    axis: 'Y'
Name: lon
    size: 1440
    type: dtype('float32')
    _FillValue: 9.96921e+36
    units: 'degrees_east'
    axis: 'X'
NetCDF variable information:
Name: eastward_eulerian_current_velocity, northward_eulerian_current_velocity
    dimensions: ('time', 'lat', 'lon')
    size: 1036800
    type: dtype('float32')
    _FillValue: 9.96921e+36
    coordinates: 'lon lat'
    horizontal_scale_range: 'greater than 100 km'
    temporal_scale_range: '10 days'
    units: 'm s-1'
```

For the evaluation of travel time of routes in a ship route planner, I am trying to find the fastest way to select the current velocity values (northward and eastward) for a specific longitude/latitude combination and time index.

**Current approach:**

First, I open multiple datasets using `xarray.open_mfdataset()`, and store it with `xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf()` after preprocessing, while keeping type float32. Then, I re-open the dataset and chunk it with autochunking by Dask. For concatenating 50 days of data (`n_days = 50`) this results in the following chunks:

- 'time': 200
- 'lon': 288
- 'lat': 240

200 * 288 * 240 * 4 bytes (float32) * 2 variables = 110.6 MB (correct?)

Storing and opening these files are expensive when `n_days` is large. For `n_days = 50`, the stored netCDF file is 3.08 GB.

```py
def load_current_data(start_date, n_days):
    # start_date: datetime(2016, 1, 1)
    # n_days: 50 --> loading 50 * 8 = 400 netCDF files
    # ds_fp: dataset filepath
    # local_paths: netCDF file pathslist

    if os.path.exists(ds_fp):
        return xr.open_dataset(ds_fp, chunks={'time': 'auto', 'lon': 'auto', 'lat': 'auto'})
    
        # Try opening current data locally, otherwise download from FTP server
    try:
        ds = xr.open_mfdataset(local_paths,
                               parallel=True,
                               combine='by_coords',
                               preprocess=convert_to_knots)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # Download files from FTP server and save to local_paths
        ds = xr.open_mfdataset(local_paths,
                               parallel=True,
                               combine='by_coords',
                               preprocess=convert_to_knots)
    ds.to_netcdf(ds_fp)
    return xr.open_dataset(ds_fp, chunks={'time': 'auto', 'lon': 'auto', 'lat': 'auto'})
```

Function for preprocessing data in `xarray.open_mfdataset()`:

```py
def convert_to_knots(ds):
    ds.attrs = {}
    arr2d = np.float32(np.ones((720, 1440)) * 1.94384)
    ds['u_knot'] = arr2d * ds['eastward_eulerian_current_velocity']
    ds['v_knot'] = arr2d * ds['northward_eulerian_current_velocity']
    ds = ds.drop_vars(['eastward_eulerian_current_velocity',
                       'eastward_eulerian_current_velocity_error',
                       'northward_eulerian_current_velocity',
                       'northward_eulerian_current_velocity_error'])
    return ds
```

`load_current_data()` returns a chunked `xarray.Dataset`, see below.

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 720, lon: 1440, time: 400)
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float32 -179.875 -179.625 -179.375 ... 179.625 179.875
  * lat      (lat) float32 -89.875 -89.625 -89.375 ... 89.375 89.625 89.875
  * time     (time) object 2016-01-01 00:00:00 ... 2016-02-19 21:00:00
Data variables:
    u_knot   (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(200, 240, 288), meta=np.ndarray>
    v_knot   (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(200, 240, 288), meta=np.ndarray>
```

To get the actual current velocities at a grid point I wrote the function below. It takes a lon/lat index and the datetime of the required netCDF file (e.g. 2016-01-01 00:00:00). This function loads the data with `load_current_data()` and persists it into memory. This is, however, only possible if it fits into the memory.
Finally the values corresponding to the lon/lat index and datetime arguments are selected with `xarray.Dataset.isel().load()`, see below.

I use dask.cache to cache computations.

```py
import datetime
from dask.cache import Cache
    
class CurrentData:
def __init__(self, start_date, n_days):
    self.start_date = start_date)
    self.n_days = n_days
    # Persist data into memory
    self.ds = load_current_data(self.start_date, self.n_days).persist()
    cache = Cache(2e9)  # Leverage two gigabytes of memory
    cache.register()  # Turn cache on globally

def get_grid_pt_current(self, date_in, lon_idx, lat_idx):
    delta = date_in - self.start_date
    day_idx = delta.seconds // 3600 // 3
    vals = self.ds.isel(time=day_idx, lat=lat_idx, lon=lon_idx).load()
    u = float(vals['u_knot'])
    v = float(vals['v_knot'])

    return u_pt, v_pt
```

Is it possible to improve the performance of this code? And, specifically:

1. The way I use `persist()` is more expensive for larger datasets. Is there a better way to efficiently acces data without `persist()` or by using it differently? I also tried `load()`, to load the data into memory. This is much faster, however, it does not work for datasets larger than memory.
2. Could setting `compute=False` in `xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf()` help improving the performance? The stored netCDF file is much smaller, henc store and opening is faster. Values need to be computed at a later stage, but I didn't managed to do this. (Using the returned `dask.delayed` object?)

Comment: Using `dask.cache` isn't recommended anymore.

To your 1st question, yes `dask.cache` uses the local scheduler (i.e. threaded or multiprocessing), and hence persist() is expensive in this case.

To the 2nd question, don't think it'll help. Instead of storing it with `to_netcdf` and re-loading, maybe try caching it to disk?